# How to filter data with infinite scroll? React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to filter data with infinite scroll? First time when page is loaded -> fetching data from the server ( only 16 items ) `{limit: 16, offset: 0}`

So if i will filter on client side i can filter only 16 items ( but i need whole data )

Is there any ways how to achieve that with infinite scroll?
**Here is my function**

```
_loadMore = () => {
    this.setState({loadingMore: true});
    this.props.getSaloons({limit: 16, offset: this.props.saloons.length});
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({loadingMore: false});
    }, 1000);
  };
```

**sql query**
`'SELECT * FROM stories LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2'`

Backend: ExpressJS + PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Have a `counter` variable in the state which is initially set to `1`. This basically calculates how much of the data needs to be loaded.

So `_loadMore` should have something like `this.props.getSaloons({limit: 16 * this.state.counter, offset: 0});`

And then you'll have to add a `scrollHandler` which you add on `componentDidMount` and remove on `componentWillUmount`

```
componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.calcScroll, 10);
    }

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.calcScroll);
}
```

Then define this `calcScroll` method which will call the `_loadMore`

```
calcScroll(){

   //This height need not be 300, you need to play around with values to get a suitable one
   if(window.scrollY > this.state.counter * 300){
      this.setState({counter:this.state.counter+1},()=>this._loadMore())
   }
}
```

Basically once you have scrolled beyond a point (`this.state.counter * 300`) in this case it updates the counter and calss `_loadMore`